# The code is not stacking in col-sm-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It should stack like so when col-sm activates:

```
[ img ]

[ content ]

[ img ]

[ content ]
```

but instead it stacks like so:

```
[ img ] [ content ]

[ img ] [ content ]
```

I've tried removing my classes to see if it affects anything but nothing changes. So how am I doing this wrong? Here's my HTML code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="homeContent">
  <div class="row homeContent-block">
    <div class="homeContent-block-image col-md-5 pull-left col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
      <img src="../../Content/images/w_city.jpg" alt="city pic" />
    </div>
    <div class="homeContent-block-image col-md-7 col-sm-12">
      <div class="homeContent-block-content-sub">
        <h1>This is a title.</h1>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row homeContent-block">
    <div class="homeContent-block-image col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
      <img src="../../Content/images/w_city.jpg" alt="city pic" />
    </div>
    <div class="homeContent-block-image col-md-7 col-md-pull-5 col-sm-12">
      <div class="homeContent-block-content-sub">
        <h1>This is a title.</h1>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

I realize that I typed `col-s-12` instead of `col-sm-12`. However, I changed it and it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Please share us your code, but don't use image.
There is a typo error (.col-s-12 instead of .col-sm-12)

Comment: @jonwa I updated the post with the HTML you shared in your screenshot. Adding in the most recent Bootstrap CSS file, the layout appears to work the way you desire with the code you provided. What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: That is great, but you should replace the relative URIs with absolute ones, — otherwise this snippet is barely useful since images are not loaded and thus not illustrating your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine on snippet, maybe you are checking before reaching it's col-sm-* breaking point?

After `.col-sm-*` breaking point:

[image]

Before `.col-sm-*` breaking point:

[image]